# How to add Azure Search Service endpoint to Traffic Manager

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I want to use traffic manager to route the request to Azure Search service on different regions. 
I have created traffic manager and added two Azure Search endpoints to traffic manager, the problem is, how to configure the health check probe on azure search service as azure search requires API-KEY on request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4daca517-f0aa-4ecb-b9ba-a318d0b97f6d/how-to-set-traffic-manager-on-azure-search?forum=azuresearch):

> 1. How can I handle different api-key of Azure Search in Traffic Manger
>
>    The following article talks about leveraging Azure Traffic Manager(TM) with Azure Search:
>      https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-performance-optimization#leveraging-azure-traffic-manager
>
>    You don't have to surface the Azure Search query keys to the TM. The users will call the TM, which will call your lightweight application (a simple web app) running on Azure. The web app will redirect the traffic to the respective Azure Search service.
> 2. How to detect available one in Traffic Manger
>
>    The TM has inbuilt endpoint monitoring support. This will monitor the health of the end-point. If the end-point is unhealthy, requests will not be routed to it unless the resource recovers and becomes healthy again.
>      https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring